# Is there any way to disable the Marker Clusterer for less than defined marker counts?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I want my Marker Clusterer; not to cluster markers less than 4 or something. It is clustering all the markers even for 2 markers.

Is there any possible way to set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option you want is not available with MarkerClusterer,  but it is an option if you use an an enhancement named: [MarkerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html). It is essentially a Google Maps v3 upgrade of the original v2 MarkerClusterer, which was then further enhanced and extended by Gary Little. It functions pretty much the same as the original MarkerClusterer, but offers more options.

Specific to your question, you may pass a set of options to the MarkerClusterer constructor function (when using MarkerClustererPlus) and include an option: **minimumClusterSize**. That will give you what you want.